# LoadTest on dummy server succeeds after setting Time to Live or TTL in HttpConnPool, but what does it do?

Tags: apache, http, httpclient, load-testing, apache-httpclient-4.x

What does the Time to Live (TTL) variable in the HttpConnPool.class from the package org.apache.http.impl.conn; do?

I was running some load tests on a dummy server. When I am passing close to 9 requests per second. I got random NoHttpResponseException, target failed to respond or dummy server failed to respond.

Then I added a property called "TTL" or "TimetoLive" and gave it a value. The HttpResponseException stopped arising. I would like to know what this variable does to prevent the NoHttpResponseException to arise in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have figured out the answer myself.

In my load testing, initially we got "NoHttpResponseException, target server @Somelink:PortNumber failed to respond." during loadtest because httpClient maintains persistent connections meaning one and same connection to send multiple requests. It is more efficient this way. There is an evictor thread which we have set for certain milliseconds or seconds. The evictor thread will remove idle connection after certain milliseconds. During production there is a possibility of having a idle connection as we do not have traffic all the time. Now during Load test, the connection will not be idle as we keep sending requests all the time to the client server. Hence the connection will not be evicted and the TTL property was set to Default value of "-1" which means infinite (This is for my application, for every application it depends on the value set by the developer).

TTL is the property that defines how long a connection must be active regardless if its idle or not. If the property is set to "-1", then the connection will remain active forever or at least until the client server closes it. The client server usually closes the connection after certain time. No server maintains a connection forever. A new connection will always be established.

During this time when the client close our connection, our server will assume that the connection is established but the client did not send a response. Hence it returns NoHttpResponseException i.e., the target server failed to respond. Adding TTL property will ensure to remove any persistent connection regardless if it is idle or not. Hence we will always have a new connection preventing an NoHttpResponseException.

I hope this helps.